# How can I fix a PS Vita that is blinking blue with no display?

Tags: ps-vita

The PS button on my PS Vita is blinking blue continuously, with no display on the screen. I tried restarting the console, but it still blinks without display.

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: What have you tried to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Source: [psu.com](https://www.psu.com/news/ps-vita-troubleshooting-tips-1-blue-flashing-light-of-death/#:%7E:text=According%20to%20the%20PS%20Vita,hand%2Dheld%20on%20or%20off.)

> According to the PS Vita manual, a blue flashing light indicates that the user has just inserted a disc or is in the process of ejecting a disc, but it can also crop up as a technical error, preventing users from turning the hand-held on or off.

Here's how to solve it:

> 1. Hold down the power on/off button for approximately 30 seconds.
> 2. Wait for a menu screen to appear that shows you the following options:
>
> - Restart the PS Vita system
> - Rebuild Database
> - Format Memory Card
> - Restore the PS Vita system
> - Update System Sofware
>
> 3. Choose Restart the PS Vita system
>
> - The system should now restart with no problems.

You said you already restarted, but it's a bit unclear if you did the three steps in order, so the steps are just being reiterated. Lastly,

> If the following steps do not fix your unit, contact Sony’s customer support.